# `lpr` fails while printing works through GUI

Tags: printing

I am trying to print files from the command line with a simple

```
lpr -Pprinter filename.pdf
```

The printer is seen by my system and ready (checked though `lpq`). The job is send, received by the printer but cancelled (that is what my printer — a Ricoh Aficio MP C400SR — is saying).

When I print files through the GUI everything works fine.

Any hint would be appreciated!

---

**Edit:**

When I submit a job, here is what I find in `/var/log/cups/access_log`:

```
localhost - - [02/Feb/2017:16:35:58 +0100] "POST /printers/RICOH HTTP/1.1" 200 370 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [02/Feb/2017:16:35:58 +0100] "POST /printers/RICOH HTTP/1.1" 200 749625 Send-Document successful-ok
```

Nothing happens in the other log files.

Comment: Inspect `/var/log/cups/*log` to start.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Nothing seems to be wrong in my logs.

Comment: Point a browser to `http://localhost:631` - can you print a test page?

Comment: Since both log entries are at the same time (including a 749,625 byte transfer)  I suspect the initial conversation with the printer fails.

Comment: I can print a test page alright. If this is a problem with the initial conversation between my computer and my printer, what could be done?